# Delete files from zip prior to extracting using PHP

Tags: php, zip

I am using PHP to upload a zip file and extracting it.  I was having problems with my validation script, and just discovered that the culprit was `Thumbs.db` files which windows creates to improve caching.  How can I delete these files prior to extracting?

Below is my attempt, but when extracting, other files have also been deleted.  I've tried using both `deleteIndex()` and `deleteName()`, but get the same results.  If I comment out the the line which deletes the Thumbs.db files, I do not experience the unintended deleted files.  My `syslog()` line only indicates that the Thumbs.db files are being deleted.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']) === true) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        //Validate files
        $name=$zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $pieces=explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$name);
        if($pieces[count($pieces)-1]=='Thumbs.db'){
            //Delete windows created thumb.db files
            syslog(LOG_INFO,'delete file '.$name.' with index '.$i);
            $zip->deleteIndex($i);  //If commented out, I do not experience the wrong files being deleted
            //Also deletes wrong files: $zip->deleteName($name);
        }
    }
    $zip->extractTo($myPath);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the archive after file manipulations and reopen it before extracting:

```
if ($zip->open($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']) === true) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
       ...    
    }
    $zip->close();
    if ($zip->open($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']) === true) {
        $zip->extractTo($myPath);
    }
}
```

I believe in your example `$zip->extractTo($myPath);` return `false`.

In your particular case it may be simpler to use system utilities to unpack the archive and then delete the files with [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I was starting to think that I might need to close it first.  I will test it when I get back home.  Why do you think it will be simpler?  I need/want to iterate over the files before unpacking anyways to make sure only appropriate files are included.

Comment: `unzip`, `find`, and `rm` were written exactly for this purpose. I see only 2 cases where php script may have advantage: running on windows host, or have complex logic to select files.

Comment: Thanks!  Needed to close and reopen before extracting.  I agree that using the OS will likely be more efficient than using PHP but might be harder to maintain.